# Unit testing for REST with Client and invokation

Tags: java, rest, unit-testing, resteasy

I would like to write unit tests for my endpoints when the endpoint is calling another application.
So far I could test if the Invocation has correct URI or method type, but I would like mock the response.

```
public Response getFormById(Integer formId) {
        Invocation invocation = prepareRequestForGettingForm(formId);
        Response response = invocation.invoke();
        return response;
    }

public Invocation prepareRequestForGettingForm(Integer formId) {
        return ClientBuilder
                .newClient()
                .register(authenticator)
                .target("localhost:8080" + "/form" + formId)
                .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .build("get");
    }
```

TEST:

```
  @Test
        public void request_getFormById_shouldContainsProperEndpointAddress() {
            String expectedUri = expectedUriBase + formId;
            Invocation invocation = mock.prepareRequestForGettingForm(formId);
            String uri = ((ClientInvocation) invocation).getUri().toString();
            assertEquals(uri, expectedUri);
            when(invocation.invoke()).thenReturn(Response.ok().build());
            Response response = formServiceBean.getFormById(formId);
            assertEquals(Response.Status.OK.getStatusCode(), response.getStatus());
        }
```

When I try to mock the invocation.invoke then I have error:

```
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY004655: Unable to invoke request

    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.invoke(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:317)
```

So can Anybody tell me how to mock it?

Is there any chance also to use Rest-Assure but do it smartly to have later on Code Coverage?

Comment: Take a look at http://wiremock.org/ which would allow you to "record" REST API calls and responses so that they could be "replayed" at a later time without needing to interact with your backend services.

Comment: @RobKielty hey, thanks but my concern is to have Code Coverage on this part of code.